# Find First Occurence of string in While Loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I need to try and find the first occurence of a string in a while loop. I'd rather not use Jquery to find the first of each element if I  can avoid it.

```
while ( $teacher_assignment_query->have_posts() ) {
    $teacher_assignment_query->the_post();
    $assignment_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    //print '$assignment_fields['title'][0] and stuff here
});
```

This prints out a list of assignments like this

```
<li class="assignments fourthgrade"><a href="#">Do worksheet 2-1</a></li>
<li class="assignments fourthgrade"><a href="#">Do worksheet 1-2</a></li>
<li class="assignments fourthgrade"><a href="#">Do worksheet 1-1</a></li>
<li class="assignments fifthgrade"><a href="#">Volunteer somewhere</a></li>
<li class="assignments fifthgrade"><a href="#">Finish science project</a></li>
```

They are in order like this, 4th grade in front of 5th grade. `$assignment_fields['grade'][0]` will print out `fourthgrade` or `fifthgrade` for each item in the loop.

Is there a way I can find WHEN it changes, so the first time it is `fourthgrade` and `fifthgrade`, so instead of the list above, I can have something like this:

```
<li class="heading">Fourth Grade</li> //new heading
<li class="assignments fourthgrade"><a href="#">Do worksheet 2-1</a></li>
<li class="assignments fourthgrade"><a href="#">Do worksheet 1-2</a></li>
<li class="assignments fourthgrade"><a href="#">Do worksheet 1-1</a></li>

<li class="heading">Fifth Grade</li> //new heading
<li class="assignments fifthgrade"><a href="#">Volunteer somewhere</a></li>
<li class="assignments fifthgrade"><a href="#">Finish science project</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$last_title = '';
while ( $teacher_assignment_query->have_posts() ) {
    $teacher_assignment_query->the_post();
    $assignment_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    if($assignment_fields['grade']!=$last_title){
        echo '<li class="heading">'.$assignment_fields['grade'].'</li>';
        $last_title = $assignment_fields['grade'];
    }
    //print '$assignment_fields['title'][0] and stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary variable to compare the current result with the previous result, and change the header when is different.
For example (metacode):

```
$previous_grade="";
while(conditions) {
    // some code to get your data
    [...]
    // Compare the current grade with the previous one
    $current_grade=$assignment_fields['grade'];
    if($current_grade!=$previous_grade) {
        print "<li class=\"heading\">$current_grade</li>";
    }
    // Go ahead with the list
    print $assignment_fields['title'][0] and other stuffs;
    // Update the temporary variable
    $previous_grade=$current_grade;
}
```